# Java EE 7 containers: initialize bean at startup without adding it to beans.xml?

Tags: java, javabeans, cdi, java-ee-7

Is there any bean type or Java EE annotation to get a bean initialized at container startup without adding the bean to beans.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.
This is what I use when I need a singleton, application scoped bean started on deploy:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Named( "myBean" )
@ApplicationScoped
@Startup
@Singleton
public class MyBean {
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {}
}
```

The `postConstruct` method is added if you need any code to be executed besides initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Singleton` bean as shown in [Initializing Singleton Session Beans](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gippq/index.html):

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupBean {

}
```